# MinGW do not support std::defaultfloat, how to lead with it?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw, precompile

Every compiler has its own set of implemented and not implemented features of the standard, that is sad but it is life.

While trying to compile our project done for VS to MinGW, I got an error with

```
std::defaultfloat

ERROR: "defaultfloat" is not member of "std"
```

It seem that his feature of C++11 is still not implemented.

I would like to make some conditional code to avoid this error, but without removing the feature:

```
#ifdef std::defaultfloat
    stream << std::defaultfloat << value;
#else
    // My own temporal equivalent
#endif
```

That of course do not work, cause of namespace, and I wonder if there is a better alternative to precompiler instructions.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? Oh, and you did enable C++11 using the `-std=c++11` flag?

Comment: Yes, I have C++11 enabled (I actually use lambda and other features of it) The version we use is MinGW 4.9.2

Comment: It's a know problem with GCC and its standard implementation, it simply isn't updated enough to fully support all of C++11. Either use some other compiler (like msvc++ or clang) with better support, or update to GCC 5. The GCC 4 series was, in some parts, very slow in C++11 adaption.

Comment: Well, that is not my decision. And to say msvc support better C++, just try some noexcept keyword or the poor support of stl and const keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write:

```
    stream.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);
    stream << value;
```

That will just work.  (It's not as pretty, but it's prettier than `#ifdef`s.)

Or you could write your own manipulator that does the same.